# How do I install Sybase Adaptive Server Enterprise PC Client 15.5 on Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, sybase, sap-ase

I am trying to Sybase client on my machine running Windows 10 Pro 64-bit. I have tried running both installation of PCC32 and PCC64 bit and encountered the same error. In the process I have also updated Java. What can I try next?

Below is error message:

ZeroGur: Windows DLL failed to load
    at ZeroGa4.b(DashoA10*..)
    at ZeroGa4.b(DashoA10*..)
    at com.zerog.ia.installer.LifeCycleManager.b(DashoA10*..)
    at com.zerog.ia.installer.LifeCycleManager.a(DashoA10*..)
    at com.zerog.ia.installer.Main.main(DashoA10*..)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.zerog.lax.LAX.launch(DashoA10*..)
    at com.zerog.lax.LAX.main(DashoA10*..)

Comment: Please verify that the installation directory (where you have unpacked the installer) does not contain spaces in the path. For example installing from "c:\install" is ok, but from "c:\install ase" folder would not work.

Comment: Where did you get the installation package from, and what's the full name of said package? when you unzip the package, what ebf* subdirectory is the package files written to?  [want to rule out possibility of trying to install in incompatible package]

Comment: @AdamLeszczyński, I have checked an the is no space in the folder name.

Comment: @markp, wht's EBF? Here is the screen shot of the directory. All my colleagues  used the same package. So, this is quite frusttrating.

Comment: OK,  it seems that the version was out dated. I downloaded the latest enterprise edition, it worked.